# connect db2 from sqoop via ssl connection giving "Security mechanism '18' is not supported" error

Tags: ssl, db2, sqoop

I am using the following sqoop command to connect to db2 database via ssl connection:

```
sqoop import -libjars /u/certificate.pfx,/u/javakeystore.jks -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true -Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3 --jar-file /u/db2jcc.jar --class-name com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --connect "jdbc:db2://<host>:<port>/<dbName>:securityMechanism=18;sslConnection=true;sslKeyStoreLocation=/u/keystore.pfx;sslKeyStorePassword=xyz;sslKeyStoreType=PKCS12;sslTrustStoreLocation=/u/trustloc/javakeystore.jks;" --username abc --query "SELECT * FROM tble " --split-by col1 --num-mappers 10 --fields-terminated-by '|' --target-dir /user/ignore-this
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.yn: [jcc][t4][20109][11222][3.53.71] Security mechanism '18' is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A504
```

I have updated the "db2jcc" jar to driver version: 3.65.77 which supports "db2.jcc.securityMechanism" as given here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052075.html

Also, I need to use db2.jcc.securityMechanism = 18 for ssl way of connection as given in the same above url.

I have been able to connect to the db directly using the userid and password. Now I am trying to connect it via ssl certificate way. 
I am using correct certificates as well. 
What I might be missing here ?

The db2 server is on z/os platform

Comment: Please confirm the platform of the Db2-server (z/os,  i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows ), as SecurityMechanism=18 may be platform specific

Comment: The Db2 server is on z/os platform. @mao

Comment: Your question is about configuration, and not about programming. Stackoverflow may not be the correct site. Find which JRE you are using from which supplier. Use jdbc trace to see what's happening under the covers. Study the advice re encryption algorithm-selection and policy-files in this link https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21986809 .  It may be wise to find another jdbc program that is working with the cert, then compare the working jre/settings/policy files, with the failing and resolve that way.

Comment: ok. Could you however, tell me one thing. If I am connecting using sslCertificate. Do I still need to give "--password xyz" in the sqoop command.